# All NSMenuItems except for one are passed to validateMenuItem:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have overriden `- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem`

All NSMenuItems of my menu are passed to this delegate method except for one, which is the one I need.

I thought all items are **always** passed to this method. If not, what am I missing ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you connected the menu to the firstResponder within IB?

Comment: @trojanfoe I can't connect the menu to First Reponder. Do you mean wire it ? I can only wire the NSMenuItems, but none of them is wired. Is it really necessary ? The other menuItems work without being connected to firstResponder

Comment: Yes you are right, the menu items not the menu and it's setting the target.  I understood that all menu items in the main menu should be wired this way.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've just tried to wire to first responder. It doesn't work. I'm wired it back to the fileOwner. (The other menuItems actually work and they are wired to the file owner.. there must be something else, but I can't notice any difference between the missing NSMenuItem and the other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found out why, it was tricky.

The IBAction wired to the NSMenuItem has to be implemented in the delegate class.

If you wire the menu to a class, and its NSMenuItem to an IBAction in another class, then the validateMenuItem method is not invoked for such NSMenuItem.